# Integrating over Conditional Probability

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm having a little trouble with a probability problem and I can't find anywhere online that answers my question.

If I am looking for $P(X = a|Y \leq z)$, is this the same as $\int_{- \infty}^z P(X = a|Y = t)dt$? My intuition says that it is, but I can't find anywhere online that says that this is true. Thanks!

Comment: You left out the marginal dist of $Y$ inside the integral. See here: https://tkchen.wordpress.com/tag/law-of-total-probability/

Comment: @YJT So it should be $\int_{- \infty}^z P(X = a|Y = t)f_Y(t)dt$?

Comment: Yes. Think of the discrete case: the conditional probability given $Y\leq z$ is the sum of all conditional probabilities of all the possible cases, given the probability of this case (cases being $Y=t$ for $t\leq z$).